# How to further classify entity subclasses?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, nhibernate-mapping

Say for e.g I have a PaymentMethod abstract entity class and there are different Payment gateways like AuthorizeNet, FirstData, Amazon, PaypalPay, etc. Where AuthorizeNet & FirstData is used for Credit card payment and the other two has its own client UI. So I need to classify these child classes as Credit Card or External Pay type. How do I do this? Is it recommended to use a DiscriminatorColumn with Joined table inheritance or can I use a simple transient field something like abstract boolean isExternalPay() in PaymentMethod and override accordingly in child classes?

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "PaymentMethod")
public abstract class PaymentMethod { }

@Entity
@Table(name = "AuthorizeNet")
public class AuthorizeNet extends PaymentMethod { }

@Entity
@Table(name = "FirstData")
public class FirstData extends PaymentMethod { }

@Entity
@Table(name = "Amazon")
public class Amazon extends PaymentMethod { }

@Entity
@Table(name = "PayPalPay")
public class PayPalPay extends PaymentMethod { }
```

Comment: You're essentially asking what design your domain model should follow, so I don't really see how any of the question tags you used are relevant. As regards your question, I would recommend that you first design the domain model without JPA, and once you're satisfied with the result, 99% of the time there will be a way to add persistence as an afterthought.

Comment: @crizzis, thanks for your response. This is a legacy code and it's running in production. Now that we need to know whether the Payment is for Credit Card or External Pay for introducing a new feature. So I was thinking about how to achieve this with a minor addition.